# init different types of same protocol using flatMap

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two `structs`, which conform to the same `protocol`. Now I want to parse some JSON which contains both types, and automatically `init` the concrete type (`struct`) and put everything in an general array of the protocol's type.

What I got so far:

```
protocol JSONSerializable {
    init?(json: [String: Any?])
}

protocol General: JSONSerializable { ... }

struct ConcreteA: General {
    init?(json: [String: Any?]) { ... }
    ...
}

struct ConcreteB: General {
    init?(json: [String: Any?]) { ... }
    ...
}

func parse(json: [String: Any?]) -> [General]? {
    // I want this to work generic like:
    return jsonDicts.flatMap { General(json: $0) } // Error: Protocol type ' General' cannot be instantiated

    // But the only way I got it working is like this, which is not really generic ;-)
    return jsonDicts.flatMap {
        if let concreteA = ConcreteA(json: $0) {
            return concreteA
        }

        if let concreteB = ConcreteB(json: $0) {
            return concreteB
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

So can you give me any hints or suggestions how I can achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: You can't really do this generically because each class will need to make an attempt at parsing the json. Swift can't magically know which unknown json maps to which unknown class. The best option might be to add a protocol extension with a static method to General and have the `if let` logic in there. At least then it will look/feel generic when parsing json.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. I must admit, that I was afraid, that this may not be possible. But now I know for sure! :-) But putting the parse method in a better place is already a win for me! :-)